# Powershell to update today's date

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am trying to use Powershell to get the item from my sharepoint list and update the Today's date field to remain current. I tried this formula and it did not work, as it gives me the error message

> The '<' operator is reserved for future use.At line:1 char:19

```
$SPWeb = GetSPWeb <https://bppr.sharepoint.com/Fraud Risk Control Investigation/Lists/Investigation Database>
$SPlist = $SPWeb.Lists["Investigation Database"]
```

Any help with this?

```
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item["Today"] = Get-Date -format s;
  $item.Update();
}
```

Comment: Also! Welcome to the SharePoint Stack Exchange! Just noticed you're a new member!

Comment: Can you show all your script ? Where you will received this error ? On script compilation or from server response ? I see that GetSPWeb already incorrect. You must use Get-SPWeb. May be some other errors.

Comment: Hi @Alex3, your feedback is very important! Please don't forget to accept the correct/helpful answer as the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are using **SharePoint Online**. In SharePoint Online, we cannot use SSOM (for example: SPSite). We need to use **CSOM or REST APIs**.

Make sure that the [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=255251) is installed and run the following commands using SharePoint Online Management Shell. Download SharePoint Online Client Components SDK from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=42038).

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Variables
$SiteURL="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/<site>"
$ListName="<list name>"

Try {
    $Cred= Get-Credential
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
    $Web = $Ctx.web

    #Get the List   
    $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
    $Ctx.Load($List)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get All List items
    $ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-host "Total Items Found:"$List.ItemCount
    #Iterate through each item and update
    Foreach ($ListItem in $ListItems)
    {
        #Set New value for List column
        $ListItem["Today"] = Get-Date -format s
        $ListItem.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    }

    Write-host "All Items in the List: $ListName Updated Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green 
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Updating List Items!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Note: Change the content within "<>" to yours.

Read [Getting started with SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps) to get more information.

Here is a demo about [how to update SPO List Items using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/07/sharepoint-online-update-list-items-using-powershell.html).

BTW, if the answer is helpful, please don't forget to **accept it as the Best Answer**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an invalid character.

Try something like the following:

Instead of `<https://bppr.sharepoint.com/Fraud Risk Control Investigation/Lists/Investigation Database>`

Try `"https://bppr.sharepoint.com/Fraud Risk Control Investigation"`

Which would mean your script now becomes:

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://bppr.sharepoint.com/Fraud Risk Control Investigation"
$SPlist = $SPWeb.Lists["Investigation Database"]
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item["Today"] = Get-Date -format s;
  $item.Update();
}
```

If any new errors come up I'll try to help.

Please note that your `GetSPWeb` should have a dash in it: `Get-SPWeb`.

Also, ensure you have the snappin for SharePoint installed if you're not using the SharePoint Management Shell. You can call

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

at the beginning of your script. This allows you to use the PowerShell ISE instead of the management shell.